# command script issue on iOS project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I get an iOS project that I want to compile with XCode.
When I build it I get the following error:

```
(!)Run custom shell script 'Get App Version'
 _________________________________________________________________
| PhaseScriptExecution Get\ App\ Version /Users........./Script-  9AAC7B315646546DC5.sh
| cd ....
| export ....
| ....
| long scripts
| .... 
|_________________________________________________________________
sed: 1: "s/CURRENT_VERSION/There ...": unescaped newline inside subtitute pattern
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1.
```

In the project when I go to Target > Build Phases there is no Run Script Phase.
**EDIT**
I found the Script in 'Build Phases' > 'Get App Version'

```
Shell: /bin/sh
Version='agvtool vers -terse'
sed -e "s/CURRENT_VERSION/$Version/g" Resources/App/version.h.tpl > GeneratedFiles/version.h
```

If I add `echo $Version` I get the following

```
There are multiple projects in this directory. agvtool does not work with multiple projects in the same directory. agvtool - Apple-generic versioning tool for Xcode projects usage: agvtool help agvtool what-version | vers [-terse] agvtool [-noscm | -usecvs | -usesvn] next-version | bump [-all] agvtool [-noscm | -usecvs | -usesvn] new-version [-all] <versNum> agvtool [-noscm | -usecvs | -usesvn] tag [-force | -F] [-noupdatecheck | -Q] [-baseurlfortag] agvtool what-marketing-version | mvers [-terse | -terse1] agvtool [-noscm | -usecvs | -usesvn] new-marketing-version <versString>
sed: 1: "s/CURRENT_VERSION/There ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: So you have checked all the target > Build Phases if any of them contains this code? They don't necessary need to be named "Run Script".

Comment: If it's not in the build scheme you are using and not in the target > build phases then I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the error:

```
sed: 1: "s/CURRENT_VERSION/There ...": unescaped newline inside subtitute pattern
```

i think the problem is the new line after the `>`. your script should be 3 lines, not 4

```
Shell: /bin/sh
Version='agvtool vers -terse'
sed -e "s/CURRENT_VERSION/$Version/g" Resources/App/version.h.tpl > GeneratedFiles/version.h
```

either that or `$Version` contains a `\n`

**Instead**

you can probably just delete that build script entirely

Comment: there isn't now that you edited it ;) try echoing ```$Version```, it is probably more than one line

Comment: Shouldn't `'agvtool vers -terse'` be `$(agvtool vers -terse)` (or back-ticks)?

Comment: the new error seems pretty clear. remove the other projects that are in the same directory. if that doesn't work, just delete the script entirely.

Answer (score 1):

The script is possibly included in the "Build" scheme as a "post-action" or "pre-action".

Click "Edit Scheme...", then click the disclosure triangle in the Build Scheme, and check entries in "Pre-actions" and "Post-actions".

Comment: there is No Actions in Pre-actions and Post actions

Comment: Hm, according your log, it's likely a "Run Script Phase" added in the "Build Phases" tab in the target editor. Ensure you're looking at the right target. Disclose also _all_ build phases, since they can be renamed to something else. I'm pretty sure, there's something  ;)

Comment: thank you I found the script in "Get App Version" tab. could you take a look at the script? does it contain errors?

Answer (score -1):

I keep stumbling into problems like this, so I'm gonna leave this working answer from a comment on this page as a reminder to myself in the future:

> This problem happens because there are multiple projects on the project folder!

The solution? Remove any extra projects, and just leave one project `.xcodeproj` that you intend to run in the first place!